# Creating an instance of a C++ class in a .lib file from C#

Tags: c#, .net, c++

As the description states. I have some static .lib files created in other rather large c++ projects containing a class I would like to be able to use in C#. What would the best way to use these classes from inside c#. The C++ libraries are not managed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By far the easiest option is to build a wrapper library in C++/CLI.

Comment: Sounds like the only reasonable option to me, since the stuff in the .lib file will almost certainly rely on the C++ runtime libraries that are in *other* .lib files, and will need to run through a linker before it can be executed.

Comment: What @marcelo-cantos said: use C++/CLI as a bridge between the managed and unmanaged worlds. It is easy.The only other options you have are (1) write a wrapper DLL that exports extern "C" functions that call onto your existing C++ objects. Then use [DllImport] in C# to call the DLL's C functions. Or (2), wrap your native C++ classes in COM interfaces and use C# COM Interop to invoke methods on the classes. The C++/CLI bridge is by far the easiest option.

Comment: @dripdeef: This should be an answer.

Comment: I've been working on this as the COM interop seems to only allow for dll's and I have lib's. I just have some trouble converting a managed string to QString etc. but I'm sure in time I will get that figured out.

Comment: @dko: No, don't use COM interop. Build a C++/CLI project and link your static libraries directly into it. Write C++/CLI classes (which are .Net classes) that act as simple wrappers for the native classes in the libraries and you're done. You can then link the C++/CLI project to your C# project. The C++/CLI compiler will automagically generate all the necessary interop code to call the native static code from the managed C++ classes. They call it IJW, for "It Just Works".

Comment: BTW, I just emended my answer to recommend C++/CLI. Managed-C++ is an obsolete precursor to C++/CLI. My apologies to anyone I confused.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos If IJW, I'm going to extremely happy. Unfortunately the .lib files use all these 3rd party libraries like QStrings etc. making the wrapper a little more complicated. I believe I have it, it will just be a while before testing it.

Comment: Well after 48 hours of trying I haven't been able to successfully get teh C++/CLI wrapper working, it throws a memory access exception.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid class exporting from native .lib files is not possible inside C#. 
But using C++ Cli, you could wrap the class and make use of it via wrapper .net class. But this approach also requires a header (.h or .hpp) file to included.

COM dlls are different story. They can be referenced in a C# project and MSVS automatically wrapps the native classes.

Answer (score 1):

What @marcelo-cantos said: use C++/CLI as a bridge between the managed and unmanaged worlds. It is easy.

The only other options you have are:

(1) Write a wrapper DLL that exports extern "C" functions that call onto your existing C++ objects. Then use `[DllImport]` and `PInvoke` in C# to call the DLL's C functions.

(2) Wrap your native C++ classes in COM interfaces and use C# COM Interop to invoke methods on the classes.

The C++/CLI bridge is by far the easiest option.